# AttributeError: module 'innvestigate' has no attribute 'create_analyzer'

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to install iNNvestigate for analysing my CNN-Model.
Environment:

- python 3.6
- keras 2.2.4
- tensorflow 2.1

```
    import innvestigate
    analyzer = innvestigate.create_analyzer("gradient", model)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'innvestigate' has no attribute 'create_analyzer'
```

I hope you could answer to my question :)

Comment: Did you name your script as innvestigate.py?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro No, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which version of Tensorflow you use. 
iNNvestiagte based on Tensorflow 1.12. After installing Tensorflow 1.12, so you can install iNNvestigate